# Loop through 5 dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, foreach, while-loop

I have a json response as array

```
$responseArray['business_discovery']['media']['data'][0]['id']
```

I'm trying to loop through the 'data' element and grab the value of 'id' and place that into an array like

```
 $idarray[0] = $responseArray['business_discovery']['media']['data'][0]['id']
```

next iteration

```
 $idarray[1] = $responseArray['business_discovery']['media']['data'][1]['id']
```

What is the best loop to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set `data` to a variable and loop through that.

```
$data = $responseArray['business_discovery']['media']['data'];
foreach($data as $item) {
    // do something with the id 
    $thisId = $item['id']
}
```